# "celebration is good to have"

Tags: word-order, sentence-choice, to-infinitive

> 1. To my mind, celebration is good to have, but I do not encourage spending too much money.
> 2. To my mind, to have celebration is good, but I do not encourage spending too much money.

Are the two sentences both grammatically correct? Or which one is better and why?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say. What do you mean by "celebration"? Are we talking about a party to promote, say, recent success at work? And you're saying that the cost of this celebration can't be too high? Or do you mean that in general, it's a good thing to go out with friends and have a good time, but it shouldn't consume too much of your budget? Or perhaps something else? It's hard to answer you without knowing what you intend to say.

Comment: I mean birthday or wedding celebrations, and I want to express it is better not to make it too expensive.

Comment: I think the usual idiom is _in my mind_, not _to my mind_. I'd just say, _"Celebration is good, but don't spend too much._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rephrase a bit to something like this:

> In my opinion, it's important to celebrate momentous occasions. I do not encourage spending too much money on the party, though. (It's the celebration that's important, not having expensive things.)

You could also tailor it to the specific occasion:

> In my opinion, it's important to celebrate birthdays. I do not encourage spending too much money on the party, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about grammatical correctness, but I would not use either in common speech. I would use celebrate as a verb rather than celebration as a noun. So I'd say "to my mind, celebrating is good..." or  more likely "to my mind, it's good to celebrate". Or if you really wanted to use a noun, then "to my mind, it's good to have a celebration..."